# Partial View not working propely in index view.

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application and using razor syntax.

In this application I am giving comment facility.

I have added a partial view, which loads the comment/Records from DB.

In below image, we can see the comment box which is called run-time for employee index view.

Now as we can see comment box, I called at run-time, which is partial view, but problem is I can add comment for only on first record...after first record that button wont work at all...

anything is missing ? 
Is there separate process when we call any partial view run-time and make in action on it ?

See the pic...

[image]

Here is the code....

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<CRMEntities.Customer>


  <link href="../../Content/Paging.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="../../Content/EventEntity.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="ListBox">
    <div id="ListHeader">   
        All customers(@Model.TotalItemCount)
    </div>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {        

    <div id="ListContent">
          <span class="ContentTitleField">@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @style="color:#1A6690;" })</span>
          @if (item.Owner != null)
          {               
            <span class="ContentSecondaryField">@Html.ActionLink(item.Owner.FullName, "Details", "Employee", new { id = item.OwnerId }, new { @style = "color:#1A6690;" })</span>          
          }
          <span class="ContentSecondaryField">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)</span>
          <span id="flagMenus">
            @Html.Action("ShowFlag", "Flagging", new { entityId=item.Id, entityType="Customer"})
          </span>
          @if (item.Opportunities.Count > 0)
          {
                        <span class="FlagOpportunity">@Html.ActionLink("opportunities(" + item.Opportunities.Count + ")", "Index", "Opportunity", new { custid = item.Id }, new { @style = "color:#fff;" })</span>
          }

           <div style="float:right;">
             @Html.Action("SetRate", "Rating", new { entityId = item.Id, rating = item.Rating, entityname = "Customer" })

           </div>
           <div id="subscribeStatus" style="float:right;">
                @Html.Action("ShowSubscribedStatus", "Subscribing", new { entityId = item.Id, entityType = "Customer" })
            </div>
          <div class="ListLinks">          
          <span class="ListEditLinks">
            <span style="float:left;">@Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })</span>
            <span class="LinkSeparator"></span>            
           </span>
           <span class="ListAddLinks">
            <span style="float:left;">@Html.ActionLink("+opportunity", "Create", "Opportunity", new { custid = item.Id }, null)</span>
            <span class="LinkSeparator"></span>
            <span>@Ajax.ActionLink("+Comment", null, null, null, new { id = item.Id, @class = "addremark" })</span>                                  
          </span>

        <div class="RemarkBox"></div>

          </div>    

             <span class="CommentAdd">

             </span>

          <div class="CommentBlock">


        </div>

         <span>@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Comment", null, null, null, new { id = item.Id, @class = "addremark" })</span>                                  



    </div>    
    } 

    <div class="PagingBox">
        @Html.Action("CreateLinks", "Pager", new { hasPreviousPage = Model.HasPreviousPage, hasNextPage = Model.HasNextPage, pageNumber = Model.PageNumber, pageCount = Model.PageCount })
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.RemarkBox').hide();

        $('a.addremark').click(function () {


            var url="@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ShowCommentBox", "Comment", new { Id = "idValue", EntityType = "Customer" }))";

            url=url.replace("idValue",event.target.id);
            $('.RemarkBox').load(url);

            $(this).closest('div').find('div.RemarkBox').slideToggle(300);
            return false;
        });


         $("a.pagenumber").click(function () {             
            var page = 0;
            page = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPagedCustomers")',
                data: { "page": page },
                success: function (data) { $("#customerlist").html(data); }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In success function you need to recall the javascript, or the jquery code that makes the button work. Is an error that taked me a lot of time. Anything uploaded by ajax or any renderpartiAl needs to recall javascript.

```
$('.RemarkBox').load(url, function() {
  //RECALL JAVASCRIPT

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how come it execute well, for first record only ?

Comment: sorry Alberto, but I am not getting where I supposed to write JScript ?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what Alberto León is saying, the partial page load will not cause the document ready event to fire, so the re-rendered elements will not have the javascript event handlers registered after the first comment is added.

To resolve this, you could put the event registration code into a function, and call this both from the document ready event and the success handler of the AJAX call.  Something like this:

```
function AssignEventHandlers() {

    $('a.addremark').click(function () {
        ....
    });

    $("a.pagenumber").click(function () {
        var page = 0;
        page = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPagedCustomers")',
            data: { "page": page },
            success: function (data) { 
                $("#customerlist").html(data);
                AssignEventHandlers();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.RemarkBox').hide();

    AssignEventHandlers();
}
```