# Script runs in Chrome but dont run in firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm using Entity Framework and MVC3,
I have following Jscript which I used in the View.

This script runs perfectly in the Crome browser but dont run in 
firefox browser(v 15.0.1)...
What to do  ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.RemarkBox').hide();

        $('a.addremark').click(function () {


            var url="@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ShowCommentBox", "Comment", new { Id = "idValue", EntityType = "Location" }))";

            url=url.replace("idValue",event.target.id);
            $('.RemarkBox').load(url);

            $(this).closest('div').find('div.RemarkBox').slideToggle();
            return false;
        });
     });

</script>
```

Comment: Try to put an `alert()` in the beginning  of your code. Just to see if some of it is fired:)

Comment: Use firebug to check the error.

Comment: ya it fired...@ begining... This line of code not working...I guess...  `var url="@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ShowCommentBox", "Comment", new { Id = "idValue", EntityType = "Location" }))";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the event parameter in the arguments, i.e.:

```
$('a.addremark').click(function (event) {
```

Comment: @Carl...Thanks a lot It works... I also have similer problem... [Same Issue ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524595/partial-view-not-working-propely-in-index-view) Can you please read this...Its Imp.